# jQuery form submission. Stopping page refresh only works in newest browsers

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

Using jQuery 1.4 to do this.

Adding a form to the body tag, nothing special about the form itself:

```
$(function() {
$('body').prepend('<form name="frmSample" id="frmSample"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="SIGN UP" /></form>');
});
```

I'm using the following to submit the form:

```
$('#frmSample').live('submit', function() {
  var formdata = $(this).serialize();

   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'http://www.example.com/Values.jsp',
       data: formdata,
       success:function() {
       submit_success();
       }
       });
  return false
  });
```

On the newest browsers (Firefox 3.5, Safari 4) this works fine. Once I go down to FF 3.0 and below or IE 7 and below this stops.

I'm a bit stuck right now. I've been searching for a good bit and have only been able to find anything mentioning something other than return false or event.preventDefault().

So looking to see if I am missing something small here, or am going in the totally wrong direction.

Comment: Is it possible that a Javascript error is occuring on the other browsers?  That would cause the rest of the JS code to be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go a step further than stopPopagation:

```
$('#frmSample').live('submit', function(e) {  
    stopEvent(e);  
    ....etc...etc
```

And the code for stopEvent:

```
function stopEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        event.originalEvent.keyCode = 0;
        event.originalEvent.cancelBubble = true;
        event.originalEvent.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

From here: http://www.openjs.com/articles/prevent_default_action/

**returnValue and preventDefault() methods**

That does what we need - but we cannot rely on the return false method for preventing the default action. Giving this code will exit the function - so if there is more to do in the function, this code cannot be used. In most of the situations I encounter, return false is enough, but in some areas, we need something more drastic.

Type the following into google for more info:

> preventDefault  stopPropagation
>   cancelBubble

Comment: You've really gone the distance on this one :)

Comment: This is what looks to have worked. Thanks you very much.

Also, thanks for pointing out more stuff to research on Google.

Comment: Just ran into this exact problem. Thanks DM (for asking) and James (for the awesome answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#frmSample').live('submit', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var formdata = $(this).serialize();

   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'http://www.example.com/Values.jsp',
       data: formdata,
       success:function() {
       submit_success();
       }
       });
  return false
  });
```

Comment: Returning false is generally a bad way to stop most events in jQuery, always grab the event in the function parameters and call stopPropagation() on it.