# Jquery - why isn't this working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Can someone tell me why the code below doesn't work. I think my theory is sound, I am just missing some vital component.

'#tweet' is the id assigned to the form submit button. I want it to check whether the input has less than 141 characters, if it doesn't, alert the user and do not submit the form.

Currently it does nothing.

```
    $('#tweet').click(function() {
   if ($('.message').val().length > 140) {
    alert('Your message much be less than or exactly 140 characters');
    return false;
   }
  });
```

Comment: could you paste the corresponding HTML part too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may be possible, that your `.message` hits more elements!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tweet').click(function(e) {
        var success = true;
        $('.message').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length > 140) {
                alert('Your message much be less than or exactly 140 characters');
                success = false;
            }
        });
        if (!succeess) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return success;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the above code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#tweet').click(function() {
    if ($('.message').val().length > 140) {
     alert('Your message much be less than or exactly 140 characters');
     return false;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

in the  section of your html after including jQuery library file. As event handlers are attached after the dom is ready.

Answer (score 1):

you should attach your behaviour to the form submit event:

```
 $('form').bind('submit',function() {
   if ($('.message').val().length > 140) {
    alert('Your message much be less than or exactly 140 characters');
    return false;
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to prevent the default action instead of returning false

```
$('#tweet').click(function( e ) {
    if ($('.message').val().length > 140) {
        alert('Your message much be less than or exactly 140 characters');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if your preventing default, you should probably go the following extra distance:

```
function stopEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        event.originalEvent.keyCode = 0;
        event.originalEvent.cancelBubble = true;
        event.originalEvent.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

There's mroe info on this in my answer to the following question:
[jQuery form submission. Stopping page refresh only works in newest browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118560/jquery-form-submission-stopping-page-refresh-only-works-in-newest-browsers)

Answer (score -3):

The ID should be `tweet` not `#tweet`

Comment: You got 4 downvotes I figured someone should tell you that $('#tweet') is absolutely correct -- why did you think it wasn't?

Comment: He distinctively said "'#tweet' is the id assigned to the form submit button". He should absolutely not have <input id="#tweet" ... />

Comment: Nope. In jQuery you use the # to select by ID. (.for classes or noting to select elements) $("") is not equivalent to document.getElementByID("")

Comment: In @Dested's defence, the OP does say the id is "#tweet", and that isn't a valid id for an HTML element. However, it also seems likely that the OP means that the id is "tweet" and is using "#tweet" as the selector string. So, @Dested's answer is technically correct but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: that's why I said he should paste the HTML part too because it can be that he named the ID as `#tweet` at the `<form>` instead of `tweet`.

if he did this way it @Dested has the right answer.